# How to get the init value in HTML to contoller in Angularjs on page load

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
<ul>                                                                
<li ng-init="formData.mdpSunday='5'">
<input ng-model="formData.mdpSunday" name="mdpSunday" type="radio" value="5">
</li>
</ul>


app.controller('doublePointCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $filter, Flash) {
var data =$scope.formData.mdpSunday;
});
```

i could not get the init values in controller while page loading

Comment: [This isn't the appropriate use of `ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).  "The only appropriate use of `ngInit` is for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`.".  "Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.".  You are basically doing this backwards, you should *always* be using the controller to set the scope, not the scope to set the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to read the `ngInit` value before Angular set the value.

**First option :**

So you can listen your `ngInit` value, and read your data when she will be set. You can use the `$watch` method :

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope) {

  //Watch you ngInit value
  $scope.$watch('data', function(){
    //When your value is set, you can retrieve it
    console.log($scope.data);
  });


}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="data='5'">

    <input type="text" ng-model="data">

  </body>
```

But, you should not have to use **$watch**. You can get a more efficient and proper way to achieve this.

**Second Option :**

You can set `ngInit` as a **function**.

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope) {

  $scope.init = function(n){
    $scope.data = n;
  }


}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="init(5)">

    <input type="text" ng-model="data">

  </body>
```

I think that the the **second** option is cleaner.

Comment: little late to reply..but great answer (the second one)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait the variable is init, `$watch` it

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/yyunfjsz/1)

```
$scope.formData = {};

$scope.$watch('formData.mdpSunday', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal);
});
```